# Matching Custom Used Symbol using ArcGIS Online

Tags: symbology, arcgis-online

Created a WebMap and published it through ArcGIS Pro about a year ago. It is now hosted on ArcGIS Online. I am now updating the layers of the map and adding new ones.

When clicking on the "Change Style" for the layer, I can see my symbol (which is not a standard symbol) at the top, but cannot select it to use anywhere else. I don't remember if I used an image (I've searched my HD and my online content, not found), and I've searched all the standard symbols.

Is there a way to use the same symbology from an existing layer to a newly uploaded layer?

---

Upon review, the answer below from Pfalbaum points out that these can only be referenced online (there is no upload from HD option), and looking at my symbol it does not show the web address I used for the symbol.

I'm afraid there may not be an answer.

[image: Custom Symbol]

Answer (score 2):

The way I always did it in Classic Map Viewer was (1) Change Style (2) Types(Unique symbols) Options (3) Click the symbol (4) Use an image (5) add the url to your symbol.

(1)  [image]

(2)  [image]

(3)  [image]

(4)  [image]

(5) https://webapp.willcountyillinois.com/gisweb/images/casino.png

I have all my symbols in a folder on a server. Bottom line is you need to keep your image files somewhere where you can host them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes I should have created a folder with all of the custom images in it when creating the symbols. I still have found no way to download a currently uploaded image back onto my HD, or use this same symbol in another layer. I appreciate your answer.

Comment: I edited my question, and your answer pointed out something I didn't realize; that the popup shown above for your casino symbol *should* show the address of the image you used (https://webapp.willcountyillinois.com/gisweb/images/casino.png) [maybe someone in ESRI should fix that]

Comment: Yeah, I've never seen/heard of a way to download the image. You might want to check out web styles: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/projects/styles.htm. It's a way to keep your symbols consistent and have the ability to reuse them. And this blog demonstrates the use of web styles in the new Map Viewer. https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/mapping/use-published-2d-symbols-in-arcgis-online/

Comment: thank you for the link to the blog post, it was informative. I will create a web style so I can reuse the symbols.

Answer (score 0):

If you open your map and right click the symbol you want to use, hit "inspect". The link to the place that image is hosted should pop up somewhere in all that code. Copy link location and add it to your custom symbols. From now on it will be in your symbol library under custom symbols.